# onchange event on lightning input tag in lwc fires but not rendering the @track property

Tags: lightning-web-components

Hi Salesforce enthusiasts,
I am calling an handler function from the OnChange event of lightning input tag. On the handler, i am trying to assign some value to a @track property which is referred on the for:each iterative to populate the table rows in markup.

My issue is that the @track property does not render as the data on the markup does not change.I have written a validation on the Onchange event handler that will change some value of the @track property.

```js
// JS Handler

updateValues(event){
var foundelement = this.records.find(ele => ele.Id ==  event.target.dataset.id);
if(event.target.name === 'PartNumber'){
        foundelement.Part_Number__c = event.target.value;
    if(!this.isNotFirstTime){
        this.handleIsLoading(true);
        this.records.forEach(res =>{        
      res.Part_Number__c = foundelement.Part_Number__c;
        this.isNotFirstTime=true;
        });
        this.handleIsLoading(false);        
        this.records = [...this.records];      
    }
}
```

```html
 <lightning-input 
    type="text" 
    class="fields" 
    variant="label-hidden" 
    label="Approved %" 
    name="Approved" 
    value={obj.Approved} 
    data-id={obj.Id} 
    onchange={updateValues}>
</lightning-input>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please can anyone share their thoughts

Comment: Based on your code sample, the HTML added is for element with name `Approved` and in `updateValues` the code runs on element with name as `PartNumber`. So you might need to handle the onchange event also for `Approved` input? Is that what is missing? Otherwise please edit your question with specific code focussing on the current issue.